# How to solve Magento 2.3 Setup Version Errors

Tags: magento2.3, setup

When running the command `n98-magerun2 sys:setup:compare-versions` I'm receiving the following errors:

```
+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| Setup                               | Module  | DB      | Data    | Status |
+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| Amasty_AdminActionsLog              | 1.0.0   | 1.0.0   | 1.0.0   | OK     |
| Amasty_Base                         | 1.5.0   | 1.5.0   | 1.5.0   | OK     |
| Amasty_Geoip                        | 1.3.2   | 1.3.2   | 1.3.2   | OK     |
| Amazon_Core                         | 3.0.0   | 3.0.0   | 3.0.0   | OK     |
| Amazon_Login                        | 3.0.0   | 3.0.0   | 3.0.0   | OK     |
| Amazon_Payment                      | 3.0.0   | 3.0.0   | 3.0.0   | OK     |
| Auctane_Api                         | 2.0.21  | 2.0.21  | 2.0.21  | OK     |
| MSP_ReCaptcha                       | 1.5.0   | 1.5.0   | 1.5.0   | OK     |
| MSP_TwoFactorAuth                   | 2.2.0   | 2.2.0   | 2.2.0   | OK     |
| MagePal_GmailSmtpApp                | 1.5.1   | 1.5.1   | 1.5.1   | OK     |
| Magefan_Blog                        | 2.8.9   | 2.8.9   | 2.8.9   | OK     |
| Magefan_Community                   | 2.0.4   | 2.0.4   | 2.0.4   | OK     |
| Magetrend_Email                     | 2.0.3   | 2.0.3   | 2.0.3   | OK     |
| Vertex_Tax                          | 100.2.1 | 100.2.1 | 100.2.1 | OK     |
| Magento_AdminNotification           |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_AdvancedSearch              |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Amqp                        |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Analytics                   |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_AsynchronousOperations      |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Authorization               |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Authorizenet                |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Backend                     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Backup                      |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Braintree                   |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_Bundle                      |         | 2.0.4   | 2.0.4   | Error  |
| Magento_BundleGraphQl               |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_BundleImportExport          |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CacheInvalidate             |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Captcha                     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Catalog                     |         | 2.2.6   | 2.2.6   | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogAnalytics            |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogGraphQl              |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogImportExport         |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogInventory            |         | 2.3.0   | 2.3.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl     |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogRule                 |         | 2.1.0   | 2.1.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogSearch               |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite           |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl    |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_CatalogWidget               |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Checkout                    |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CheckoutAgreements          |         | 2.2.0   | 2.2.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Cms                         |         | 2.0.2   | 2.0.2   | Error  |
| Magento_CmsGraphQl                  |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_CmsUrlRewrite               |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl        |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Config                      |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_ConfigurableImportExport    |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_ConfigurableProduct         |         | 2.2.1   | 2.2.1   | Error  |
| Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl  |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_ConfigurableProductSales    |         | 2.2.0   | 2.2.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Contact                     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Cookie                      |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Cron                        |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CurrencySymbol              |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_Customer                    |         | 2.0.13  | 2.0.13  | Error  |
| Magento_CustomerAnalytics           |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_CustomerGraphQl             |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_CustomerImportExport        |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Deploy                      |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Developer                   |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Dhl                         |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Directory                   |         | 2.0.2   | 2.0.2   | Error  |
| Magento_Downloadable                |         | 2.0.2   | 2.0.2   | Error  |
| Magento_DownloadableGraphQl         |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_DownloadableImportExport    |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Eav                         |         | 2.1.1   | 2.1.1   | Error  |
| Magento_EavGraphQl                  |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Elasticsearch               |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Email                       |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_EncryptionKey               |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Fedex                       |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_GiftMessage                 |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_GoogleAdwords               |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_GoogleAnalytics             |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_GoogleOptimizer             |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_GraphQl                     |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_GroupedImportExport         |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_GroupedProduct              |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl       |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_ImportExport                |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_Indexer                     |         | 2.1.0   | 2.1.0   | Error  |
| Magento_InstantPurchase             |         | 1.0.0   | 1.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Integration                 |         | 2.2.1   | 2.2.1   | Error  |
| Magento_LayeredNavigation           |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Marketplace                 |         | 1.0.0   | 1.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_MediaStorage                |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_MessageQueue                |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Msrp                        |         | 2.1.3   | 2.1.3   | Error  |
| Magento_Multishipping               |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_MysqlMq                     |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_NewRelicReporting           |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_Newsletter                  |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_OfflinePayments             |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_OfflineShipping             |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_PageCache                   |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Payment                     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Paypal                      |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_Persistent                  |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_ProductAlert                |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_ProductVideo                |         | 2.0.0.2 | 2.0.0.2 | Error  |
| Magento_Quote                       |         | 2.0.8   | 2.0.8   | Error  |
| Magento_QuoteAnalytics              |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_QuoteGraphQl                |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_ReleaseNotification         |         | 2.2.0   | 2.2.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Reports                     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_RequireJs                   |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Review                      |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_ReviewAnalytics             |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Robots                      |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Rss                         |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Rule                        |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Sales                       |         | 2.0.10  | 2.0.10  | Error  |
| Magento_SalesAnalytics              |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_SalesInventory              |         | 1.0.0   | 1.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_SalesRule                   |         | 2.0.3   | 2.0.3   | Error  |
| Magento_SalesSequence               |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_SampleData                  |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Search                      |         | 2.0.4   | 2.0.4   | Error  |
| Magento_Security                    |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_SendFriend                  |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Shipping                    |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Signifyd                    |         | 2.2.0   | 2.2.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Sitemap                     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Store                       |         | 2.1.0   | 2.1.0   | Error  |
| Magento_StoreGraphQl                |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Swagger                     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_SwaggerWebapi               |         | 1.0.0   | 1.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync          |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Swatches                    |         | 2.0.3   | 2.0.3   | Error  |
| Magento_SwatchesGraphQl             |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation   |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Tax                         |         | 2.0.3   | 2.0.3   | Error  |
| Magento_TaxGraphQl                  |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_TaxImportExport             |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Theme                       |         | 2.0.2   | 2.0.2   | Error  |
| Magento_Tinymce3                    |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Translation                 |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Ui                          |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Ups                         |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_UrlRewrite                  |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl           |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_User                        |         | 2.0.3   | 2.0.3   | Error  |
| Magento_Usps                        |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_Variable                    |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Vault                       |         | 2.0.3   | 2.0.3   | Error  |
| Magento_Version                     |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Webapi                      |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_WebapiAsync                 |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_WebapiSecurity              |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_Weee                        |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
| Magento_WeeeGraphQl                 |         |         |         | Error  |
| Magento_Widget                      |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_Wishlist                    |         | 2.0.1   | 2.0.1   | Error  |
| Magento_WishlistAnalytics           |         | 2.0.0   | 2.0.0   | Error  |
+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+--------+

  143 setup errors were found!
```

I've tried running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and clearing all cache. But nothing has worked up to this point. How to troubleshoot / solve these errors?

Comment: You can check Magento modules inside the require declaration list. Make sure module versions of module with error above is not written as `version of *`. For example, `"magento/framework": "*" ,` it should be the exact module number instead

Comment: like in your case instead of `"magento/module-admin-notification": "*",` it should be `"magento/module-admin-notification": "2.0.0",`

Comment: Sorry, dumb question but where exactly do you check / edit these values?

Comment: in magento composer.json file

Comment: inside your Magento root directory

Comment: after you edit the composer.json file dont forget to run `composer update`

Comment: Run this command `php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade` then `s:up` and then compare version.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Thanks, but I ran those and still receiving same errors

Comment: @magefms Just tried this, didn't see any of these listed in my `composer.json` file but they were all in the `composer.lock` file with versions listed

Comment: run 'php bin/magento list' and see what error it show

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad ran that but it just shows a list of commands, no errors

Comment: just let me know you are having issue in using tool or have issue in Magento as well ?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Thanks, no issues using the tool, just trying to resolve setup errors that I noticed after running `n98-magerun2 sys:setup:compare-versions`